# Solving $m\ddot{x} = atx$ using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, mathematical-physics, closed-form, frobenius-method

If we have the differential equation in $x$ w.r.t the time $t$:

> $$m\ddot{x} = atx\tag{1}$$

I'm trying to solve $(1)$, with the initial conditions $x(0) := x_0$ and $v(0) := v_0$,  using Frobenius method. So let $x$ be a infinite sum

$$x(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nt^n$$

Then we will get

$$\dot{x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nb_nt^{n-1}\,\,\,;\,\,\,\ddot{x} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)b_nt^{n-2}$$

setting in the equation $(1)$ we get

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty mn(n-1)b_nt^{n-2} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty ab_nt^{n+1} = 0$$

Now we want to derive the recurrence relation for the constants. So what I did was, in the first summation set $n-2 \to n'$ and then

$$\sum_{n'=0}^\infty m(n'+2)(n'+1)b_{n'+2}t^{n'} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty ab_nt^{n+1} = 0 \implies $$

$$2mb_2 + \sum_{n'=1}^\infty m(n'+2)(n'+1)b_{n'+2}t^{n'} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty ab_nt^{n+1} = 0$$

Now use $n' \to n+1$ such that $n = n'-1$ and we get

$$2mb_2 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty m(n+3)(n+2)b_{n+3}t^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty ab_nt^{n+1} = 0 \implies $$

$$2mb_2 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left \{m(n+3)(n+2)b_{n+3}\ - ab_n \right \}t^{n+1} = 0$$

We conclude then that $b_2 = 0$ and that $$b_{n+3} = \frac{a}{m(n+3)(n+2)}b_n$$

**Question:***Is this correct? There exists a better form (closed form) to set this coefficients for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ? How can I use the constants $x_0,v_0$ in the answer for $x$?*

What I tried was to see that $b_0, b_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ are the constants that are free so they should be somehow correlated to the initial conditions. Also we get that, for example

> $$b_{3n} = \frac{(a/m)^n}{(3n)!}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (3i+1)b_0 \tag{2}$$

for $n \geq 1$.

---

**EDIT:** Working on this problem I was able to set this relations below. Using that we have $(2)$ and also that it's easy to show

> $$b_{3n+1} = \frac{(a/m)^n}{(3n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(3i+2)b_1; \,\, n\geq 1 \tag{3}$$

We can note that

$$x(t) = b_0 + b_1t+b_3t^3+b_4t^4+b_6t^6+b_7t^7 + \dots= b_0+b_1t + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{3n}t^{3n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{3n+1}t^{3n+1}$$

So we'll get

$$x(t) = b_0 + b_1 t\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{a}{m}\right)^n \left[ \frac{1}{(3n)!}t^{3n}b_0\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(3i+1) + \frac{1}{(3n+1)!}t^{3n+1}b_1\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(3i+2)\right]$$

We can bring the products in front and instead of having two we get just one but I couldn't get so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m\ddot x(t)=a\,t\,x(t)\tag 1$$
We look for a power series solution of the form
$$x(t)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^{k}\tag 2$$
We have
$$
\begin{align}
\dot x(t)&=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}k\,a_kt^{k-1}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)a_{k+1}t^{k}\\
\ddot x(t)&=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}k(k+1)a_{k+1}t^{k-1}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}t^{k}\tag 3
\end{align}
$$
Substituting (2) and (3) in the eq. (1) we have
$$
m\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}t^{k}=a t \sum _{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^{k}\tag 4
$$
and, putting $\frac{a}{m}=\gamma$, the eq. (4) becomes
$$
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}t^{k}-\gamma \sum _{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^{k+1}=2a_2+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\Big[(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}-\gamma a_{k-1}\Big]t^k=0\tag 5
$$
The equality (5) holds for all $t$ if each term is separately $0$. Therefore, 
$$
\begin{align}
a_2&=0\\
(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}&=\gamma a_{k-1}
\end{align}
$$
For $k=3$, we obtain $5\cdot 4\,a_5=20a_5=a_2=0$ and by induction,  $$a_2=a_5=a_8=\ldots=a_{3k-1}=0\;\;\text{ for }\;k=1,\, 2,\ldots$$
For the terms $a_{3k}$ and $a_{3k+1}$ we find in the same way
$$
\begin{align}
a_{3k}&=\frac{\gamma^k a_0}{[(3k)(3k-1)][(3k-3)(3k-4)]\cdots [6\cdot 5][3\cdot 2]}\;\;\text{ for }\;k=1,\, 2,\ldots\\
a_{3k+1}&=\frac{\gamma^k a_1}{[(3k+1)(3k)][(3k-2)(3k-3)]\cdots [7\cdot 6][4\cdot 3]}\;\;\text{ for }\;k=1,\, 2,\ldots
\end{align}
$$
Thus the general solution of (1) is
$$
x(t)=a_0+ a_1t+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{3k}\,t^{3k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{3k+1}\,t^{3k+1}
$$

Observe that equation $x''(t)-\gamma t x(t)=0$ is known in literature as Airy differential equation and the solution might be written as
 $$x(t)=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{t}\left[\lambda_1 I_{-1/3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\gamma}t^{3/2}\right)-\lambda_2I_{1/3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\gamma}t^{3/2}\right)\right]$$

where $I_{\nu}(z)$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ costants, or usually expressed in terms of the Airy functions $\mathrm{Ai}(z)$ and $\mathrm{Bi}(z)$
$$x(t)=\mu_1 \mathrm{Ai}\left(\gamma^{1/3}t\right)+\mu_2 \mathrm{Bi}\left(\gamma^{1/3}t\right)$$
where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ costants.

Answer (score 2):

Direct substitution into the original ansatz for $x(t)$ gives $x_0=b_0,v_0=b_1$. This is one reason the Frobenius method is well-suited to IVPs and, by comparison at least, poorly suited to BVPs: the coefficients in the expansion are trivially related to derivatives at the point of expansion.

Past that point, as a sanity check, it should be no surprise that you get $b_{n+3}$ is equal to something times $b_n$ because the LHS has its indices "reduced" by 2 by the derivatives and the RHS has its indices "increased" by 1 by the factor of $t$. So the indices at least make sense.

For dimensional reasons it might make more sense to factor out $\frac{a}{m}$ from the $n$-dependent stuff (but that's just a matter of style really).

Comment: This is great. This answers most of my question. I'm just waiting if someone will figure out the closed form of the coefficients, if no answer be given I'll accept your answer as the one. Thank's (+1)

Comment: @RafaelWagner I don't think you can do that much better than your expression for $b_{3n}$ (with $b_0$ replaced by $x_0$), the analogous one for $b_{3n+1}$, and $b_{3n+2}=0$. If you like, you can use the "triple factorial", but this is not very popular notation compared to the factorial or even the double factorial.

Comment: I'll edit some work that I've done so far. But it seems you're right

Comment: @RafaelWagner Clarifying my previous comment, your formula can be equivalently written as $b_{3n}=\left ( \frac{a}{m} \right )^n \frac{(3n-2)!!!}{(3n)!} b_0$.